# How to add SAML IdP-Initiated SSO support to existing application in Azure

Tags: .net, angular, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

Our current application is an Angular frontend with a C# API backend hosted in Azure using Entra ID for authentication.  We are being asked to set up an IdP-Initiated SAML integration with a third party application (not hosted in Azure) where our application is a Service Provider and the third party application is the Identity Provider.  Essentially, the idea is a user will be logged into the third party system, click a button on a patient record in their system, at which point the third party system will pass a SAML assertion to us and the user should land on the corresponding patient record in our system (patient id provided in the SAML assertion), assuming the user already exists on our side as well.

I've done some SAML training over the last few days and have a better understanding of the concepts, but feel like I'm chasing my tail trying to find concrete examples of how to proceed.

Here's what I've done so far:

The vendor of the third party application has provided us with their metadata xml file and requested that we provide our ACS URL and Entity Id.

In the Azure portal, I have set up the third party application as an external identity provider by importing their XML file in External Identities>All Identity Providers>SAML/WS-Fed identity providers.

For our ACS URL, I provided them with the "SAML -P sign on endpoint" under the enterprise applications Endpoints tab.  For the Entity Id, I provided them with the entity id from the XML file referenced in "Federation metadata document" in the same tab.

With these settings, it is definitely hitting our side of the fence, but it is throwing an error "AADSTS90121: Invalid empty request."  Using dev tools we have confirmed that the SAML assertion is coming through and is valid.

So a couple of questions:

1. Are these the correct settings out of Azure for the values they are requesting?
2. Where is the appropriate place to handle the SAML assertion within the application, in the frontend or as an API endpoint?

I've been spinning my wheels and any help or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: an ACS URL isn't a sign-on endpoint. It's the last URL the SAML goes to after sign-in. If a user hits your app with a patient ID and they're not signed-in to your app, redirect their browser to their SSO endpoint and get their attributes at your ACS URL. No need for Azure. You can use RelayState to store the patient id (though this is HUGE security problem so use something that can be resolved to the patient id instead). Once you get their attributes at your ACS, create them a session and "log them in" to your app, based on the SAML attributes' TTL.